# Spring Boot Reactor Netty Thread Pool

Tags: spring-boot, netty, threadpool, java-threads, reactor-netty

Spring Boot Reactor Netty Thread Pool

From what I have read online about Netty thread pool, the default number of thread pool is equal to 2 * no of processor cores.

Now from what I've read there's also a way to customize the size of event loop threads programmatically

```
  @Bean
  public NioEventLoopGroup nioEventLoopGroup() {
    return new NioEventLoopGroup(16);
  }
```

What would happen if we set this number to more than 2 * no of processor? extreme case: set this to like a really huge number: like 10,000 threads or more.

I tried this locally and it still runs like normal... can someone shed a light?

What would be the most optimal configuration for a production-grade use case? Example: for x cores machine: y number of threads is optimal, more or less would impact negatively to performance